# Can you access active directory without using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

Tags: .net, sql-server, active-directory

I have a method that extract user group from active directory. However the problem is that it is using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement; which when i want to deploy on sql-server as stored procedure, but i have to make it **unsafe**.

Is there any way to get the groups without making the database unsafe ?

P.S.
Usefull link about my problem https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/officeocs/en-US/c376ae22-da56-4cf7-b538-f7564f19595d/assembly-systemdirectoryservices-could-not-be-called-from-clr-stored-procedure?forum=sqlnetfx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is another way. The process is described in detail here: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/03/30/sql-server-query-active-directory-data-using-adsi-ldap-linked-server/

It involves setting up a linked server that points to AD, with a logon that can authenticate to the domain. Then you use [`OPENQUERY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to query that linked server.

Something like this (assuming you called your linked server "ADSI"):

```
SELECT * FROM OpenQuery (
ADSI,
'SELECT *
FROM ''LDAP://DC=domain,DC=com''
WHERE objectClass = ''User''
')
```